# How to debug delay signed silverlight assemblies?

Tags: .net, silverlight, assemblies, code-signing

Our .Net 3.5 projects are delay signed and are registred with sn -Vr to allow debugging these assemblies on dev machines.

Recently we ported some projects to Silverlight 3.0 and found out that sn -Vr won't allow to execute a delay signed silverlight assembly through iexplorer.

Is there a way to execute a delay signed silverlight application in iexplorer?

Fully signing on dev machines is not an option and not signing silverlight assemblies on dev machines will cause us some trouble with their strong name because we make heavy use of reflection, so we're kind of stuck there...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "by design", Silverlight does not support delay signed assemblies unfortunately.

I'd recommend using a separate .snk file that you generate for development use; then if you are doing code signing, you'll need to do some additional work for official builds.

Comment: That's inconvenient... I saw in your profile that you are working on Silverlight 4, nice. Do you have any insight on why it is "by design"? I guess it is for security reason but I fail to see what is the security risk to execute a silverlight assembly that is explicitly registered for verification skipping with sn -Vr. By any chance, do you know an unofficial way (read dirty hack) of skipping the verification in iexplorer? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know it is a security mitigation. No way to skip it with the shipping Silverlight, sorry.